# Unable to start the queue manager getting error Failed to start the Service, status=1057

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using mq version 8.0.0.2,we hvae a active passive configuration.while we switch over the server from active to passive node we unable to start the one us Queue Manager getting below error. and we have we have observer below error in queue manager logs nad FDC file.can any help on this is crititcal application.

---

Error:

Generic service 'IBM WebSphere MQ (AMHMQ)' could not be brought online (with error '1057') during an attempt to start the service.

---

FDC File:

```
| Build Date        :- Feb 17 2015                                            |
| Build Level       :- p800-002-150217.2                                      |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| UserID            :- SYSTEM                                                 |
| Process Name      :- C:\Windows\Cluster\rhs.exe                             |
| Arguments         :-                                                        |
| Addressing mode   :- 64-bit                                                 |
| Process           :- 00020948                                               |
| Thread            :- 00000002                                               |
| Session           :- 00000000                                               |
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  |
| Last HQC          :- 0.0.0-0                                                |
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 0.0.0-0                                                |
| Last ObjectName   :-                                                        |
| Major Errorcode   :- xecF_E_UNEXPECTED_SYSTEM_RC                            |
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- MSGAMQ6119                                             |
| Probe Severity    :- 2                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ6119: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred   |
|   (***CMQMException Caught***: Failed to start the Service, status=1057)    |
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      |
| Comment1          :- ***CMQMException Caught***: Failed to start the        |
|   Service, status=1057
```

---

AMQERR01.Log:

```
----- amqxfdcp.c : 829 --------------------------------------------------------
9/3/2018 01:38:23 - Process(19732.115) User(SYSTEM) Program(rhs.exe)
                      Host(XXXXXXXXXX) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2)
AMQ6183: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 19732.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 874 --------------------------------------------------------
9/3/2018 01:42:17 - Process(20948.153) User(SYSTEM) Program(rhs.exe)
                      Host(XXXXXXX) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2)
AMQ6119: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (Timed-out waiting for
MSCS resource 'QM1', to be terminated)

EXPLANATION:
MQ detected an unexpected error when calling the operating system. The MQ error
recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 829 --------------------------------------------------------
9/3/2018 01:42:17 - Process(20948.153) User(SYSTEM) Program(rhs.exe)
                      Host(XXXXXXX) Installation(AMHMQ)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.2)
AMQ6183: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 20948.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 874 --------------------------------------------------------
```

@ Kindly help on this issue.

@JoshMc: Yes we have raised the PMR and also we are checking same error code 1057 with Windows team they are collecting event logs for better understanding.
we have shared the windows event logs to IBM.

Comment: Critical application support should be obtained from an appropriate support contract with the software vendor,  in this case IBM not from stack overflow posts.  Have you opened a sev 1 PMR with IBM and escalated to a duty manager,  have you taken a early trace capturing the start up failure and gathered the trace and other relevant configuration details using runmqras to attach to the PMR?

Comment: Praveen, you can respond with a comment down here, just fill in the box and click Add Comment. DId you review my suggestions and have you done any of them?

Comment: Praveen, please use the comments section down here under the question for comments, putting in the question does not add any value unless it is something more substantial like additional error logs that can use the extra formatting or provide more information.  Just click the "[add a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171540/unable-to-start-the-queue-manager-getting-error-failed-to-start-the-service-sta#)" link below to open the comment window to type in, then click the "Add Comment" button when you are ready to save it.

Comment: A quick google search turned up this `C:\>net helpmsg 1057` returns `The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.` is the account that you configure MQ with on the primary node a Domain account or a Local account?  If a local account it is documented to not be possible.

Comment: [FAQ on MQ for Failover Clustering (MSCS Clustering)](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2017/06/29/faq-mq-failover-clustering-mscs-clustering/) 7) Can we configure IBM MQ Service with local user account in a MQ Server used by MSCS ?  A) Local accounts for MSCS setup doesn’t work, it has to be a domain account. You must use a domain account to run your IBM MQ Service. Make sure that this domain account exists in domain mqm group and the domain mqm group exists in the local mqm group on each computer in the cluster. Make the nodes of the MSCS cluster members of a domain. CONTINUED in NEXT

Comment: Your aim is to make your cluster of two computers look like a single computing resource. Remember that an account that is local to one computer does not exist on the other one. Even if you create an account with the same name on the other computer, its security identifier (SID) is different, so, when your application is moved to the other node, the permissions do not exist on that node.